# How to persist an array of images, returning a list of documentURLs so I can re load them later in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, persistence

Trying to persists an array of UIImage and return an array of the saved file paths in func encodeReview, but keep hitting

> Mutation of captured var 'encodedImages' in concurrently-executing code

at encodedImages.append(_url)

The goal is to save an array of Review with the attached imageURL as JSON so I can re-load the photos.

```
//
//  Review.swift
//  resRec
//
//  Created by King F. Wong on 03/10/2023.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit




struct Review: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var restaurant: Restaurant
    var userReview: UserReview
    
    init(id: UUID=UUID(),
         restaurant: Restaurant,
         userTags: [Tag],
         userOverallRating: Double,
         userFoodRating: Double,
         userAmbianceRating: Double,
         userServicesRating: Double,
         userImages: [UIImage]
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.restaurant = restaurant
        self.userReview = UserReview(
            tags: userTags,
            overallRating: userOverallRating,
            foodRating: userFoodRating,
            ambianceRating: userAmbianceRating,
            servicesRating: userServicesRating,
            images: userImages
        )
    }
    
}

extension Review {

    struct UserReview: Identifiable {
        
        let id: UUID
        var tags: [Tag]
        var overallRating: Double
        var foodRating: Double
        var ambianceRating: Double
        var servicesRating: Double
        
        var images: [UIImage]
        
        init(id: UUID=UUID(), tags: [Tag], overallRating: Double, foodRating: Double, ambianceRating: Double, servicesRating: Double, images: [UIImage]) {
            self.id = id
            self.tags = tags
            self.overallRating = overallRating
            self.foodRating = foodRating
            self.ambianceRating = ambianceRating
            self.servicesRating = servicesRating
            self.images = images
        }
    }
    
}

extension Review {
    // load sample photos
    static let sampleReviewImages: [UIImage]

}

extension Review {
    
    func encodeReview (review: Self) async {
        
        var encodedImages: [URL] = []
        
        let encodedRestaurant = review.restaurant.encodingRestaurant(rawRestaurant: review.restaurant)
        
        try? await Task {
            for userImage in review.userReview.images {
                if let _url = try? await saveImage(image: userImage) {
                    encodedImages.append(_url)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}


extension Review {
    
    static let globalReviews: [Review] =
    [
        Review(restaurant: Restaurant.sampleData,
               userTags: sampleReviewTags(),
               userOverallRating: 9.0,
               userFoodRating: 9.0,
               userAmbianceRating: 8.5,
               userServicesRating: 8.0,
               userImages: sampleReviewImages
              )
    ]
}


func saveImage(image: UIImage) async throws -> URL {
    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
        let manager = FileManager()
        if let docUrl = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first{
            let uniqueName = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
            let url = docUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(uniqueName).jpg")
            
            let task = Task {
                try imageData.write(to:url)
                return url
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You don't need to declare `saveImage` as `async` since you are using `Task`